# Search Arrays to Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 dimensional array like

```
$events = array(
    array(
        'desc'  => 'Cancer Webinar',
        'date'  => '20201219'
    ),
    array(
        'desc'  => 'CSR Management',
        'date'  => '20200812'
    ),
    array(
        'desc'  => 'Company Anniversary',
        'date'  => '20200309'
    )
);

$look = array('20201219','20200309');
```

result: **array('Cancer Webinar','Company Anniversary');**

The function call search from array list ($look) then find it to $events.

From the code above shoud return:
array('Cancer Webinar','Company Anniversary');

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please provide what you have done so far, instead of asking them to do it, so that users can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second array will just search by `date` use the following code

```
function search_from_array($array, $events) {
        $result = [];
        foreach($events as $event) {
            if(in_array($event['date'], $array)) {
                array_push($result, $event['desc']);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
}
search_from_array($look, $events);
```

you can develop it more to can search with any key in the multidimensional array.

in case you want to search but many keys just add OR in the condition and make the same code for other keys like this

```
    if(in_array($event['date'], $array) || in_array($event['desc'], $array))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make $look a dict, then check if the date key exist.

```
    $events = array(
        array(
            'desc'  => 'Cancer Webinar',
            'date'  => '20201219'
        ),
        array(
            'desc'  => 'CSR Management',
            'date'  => '20200812'
        ),
        array(
            'desc'  => 'Company Anniversary',
            'date'  => '20200309'
        )
    );

    $look = array('20201219','20200309');
    $look_dic = array_flip($look);
    foreach($events as $event){
        if(isset($look_dic[$event["date"]])){
            $result[] = $event["desc"];
        }
    }
    var_dump($result);
```